# upload files using Invoke-WebRequest on windows

Tags: windows, upload

I am trying to build a software using jenkins and after the build I need to upload the files to a webserver with an API using command line. I have tried Invoke-WebRequest but have no luck with it.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Header @{"{"X-Octopus-ApiKey"="<APIKEY>"} -Method Post  -InFile 'file.zip' -Uri http://example.com/api/packages/raw
```

Using the above command I am always getting 400 Bad Request

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"X-Octopus-ApiKey"="API-P5CI8B7HKR460OPA ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Use Wireshark to sniff a 'working' POST (from a browser maybe) and the WebRequest PowerShell makes.

Comment: got it running with a different solution.